# Parse a file with multiple common delimiters C

Tags: c, parsing, command-line, text-files

I'm working on a basic command line music library in C that lets you open a file via command line, and add information like an artist, song title, and year published. Once it exits, it then writes that information back into the same file.

The problem I'm having is trying to find a solution to correctly parse the text file.

For example, the input file will look something like this:

```
Title: Heirloom, Artist: Basenji, Year Published: 2014
Title: With Me, Artist: Cashmere Cat, Year Published: 2014
```

The project I'm working on specifies (against common practice) that we store one line of information in a `struct Song` that looks like this:

```
struct Song {
    char title[250];
    char artist[250];
    int year_published;
};
```

Each `Song` is stored in array of type `struct Song`, called `music_lib[]`.

I know how to separate each line into one specific `struct Song` by doing:

```
while(fscanf(input_file, "%s %s %ld", *temp_title, *temp_artist, *temp_year) != EOF)
    copy_song_to_music_library(temp_title, temp_artist, temp_year);
```

What I don't know how to do is how to properly parse the text file so that when I have a known format:

`Title: Heirloom, Artist: Basenji, Year Published: 2014`

For my title variable, I get "Heirloom" (and Title: is stripped out), for my artist variable, I get "Basenji"  (with artist: stripped out), and for my year variable I get 2014 (with year published: stripped out).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `"Title: %s, Artist: %s, Year Published: %ld"` ?

Comment: @Tomasz Kłak `"Title: %s,...` will not work for a title with a space like `"With Me"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change

```
while(fscanf(input_file, "%s %s %ld", *temp_title, *temp_artist, *temp_year) != EOF)
```

to

```
while(fscanf(input_file, "Title: %s, Artist: %s, Year Published: %ld", *temp_title, *temp_artist, *temp_year) != EOF)
```

Also, you need to check for the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure proper reading.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) of `fscanf()`

> . . . return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

*Some related reference:*

The signature of this (and family) function is

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

Where, `const char *format` is described as

> The *format* string consists of a sequence of directives which describe how to process the sequence of input characters.

and the expected format for `format` is [emphasis mine]

> A directive is one of the following:
>
> • A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.
>
> **• An ordinary character (i.e., one other than white space or '%'). This character must exactly match the next character of input.**
>
> • A conversion specification, which commences with a '%' (percent) character. A sequence of characters from the input is converted according to this specification, and the result is placed in the corresponding pointer argument. If the next item of input does not match the conversion specification, the conversion fails-this is a matching failure.

NOTE:

However, to make it more generalized, I'll recommend using `fgets()` to take the input, then using `strtok()` to tokenize the input and use.

Comment: @Gopi This time, next time you do. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll check out fgets() as well :)

Comment: `fscanf(input_file, "Title: %s,...` will not correctly scan `"Title: With Me, ..."` as the string to be saved in `temp_title` will stop at "With" rather than "With Me".