# Easiest way to split a string based on a few set words in C

Tags: c, string, token

I'm working on a project in C where I'm reading in lines from a file with fgets(). The format of each file is like this:

```
Title: Name Here, Artist: Artist Here, Year Published: 2014
```

Currently I'm storing the line above as a single string. The problem is, I have an array of structures called `music_lib` that is of type `Song` that looks like this:

```
struct Song
{
    char title[250];
    char artist[250];
    int year_published;
};
```

I want to be able to split the string I have and store `Name Here` in `title`, `Artist Here` in `artist`, and `2014` in `year_published`, while throwing away the rest of the string I got from the file.

I've looked at `strtok()` but it seems pretty difficult since I want to disregard `Title:` and other words, and commas. Is there an easy way to I guess find a substring `Title:`, store whatever is after that up until the comma, then find the substring `Artist:` store whatever is there until I hit a comma.. and then do the same thing for `Year Published`?

Comment: What will you do if the title is something like `How to Become an Artist: 101 Extremely Useful Tips`?

Comment: Didn't you ask basically the same question yesterday?

Comment: @iharob I've tried using `strstr` with a bunch of functions to try and parse each item out.. however the code turned into spaghetti and didn't work well :/

Comment: @Alex try `chux`'s solution.

Comment: @luserdroog Originally, I was trying to just get the text out of the file and separating it that way. However, I learned `scanf` shouldn't really be used in my case so I used `fgets()`. This question is more about splitting a string inside of a program, rather than parsing it from a input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sscanf()`, `"%[]"` (for title and artist) and `"%n"` to locate the end will parse the buffer.

```
struct Song songa;
int n = 0;
int cnt = sscanf(buf, 
    " Title: %249[^,], Artist: %249[^,], Year Published: %d %n", 
    songa.title, songa.artist, &songa.year_published, &n);
if (cnt == EOF) Handle_EOF();
if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') Success();
else Handle_BadBuffer();
```

---

Format break-down  `" Title: %249[^,], Artist: %249[^,], Year Published: %d %n"`

`" "`  Consume optional leading white-space.
`"Title:"` Consume "Title:".
`" "`  Consume optional white-space.
`"%249[^,]"` Scan and save up to 249 non-`','` `char` into `.title`.  Append `'\0'`.
`", Artist:"` Consume ", Artist:".
`" "`  Consume optional white-space.
`"%249[^,]"` Scan and save up to 249 non-`','` `char` into `.artist`.  Append `'\0'`.
`","` Consume ",".
`" "`  Consume optional white-space.  (Not really needed here)
`"%d"` Scan and save an `int` into `.year_published`.
`" "`  Consume optional white-space.  (catch the \n)
`"%n"` Save current offset of `buf` scanning is occuring.

`n` will only be set if scanning gets to the end.  So a non-zero value indicates success.  and it *should* index to the end of the string.

---

[Edit]

I now see a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27896004/2410359).  It is good to *not* use this format with the `fscanf()` approach discussed there.

Anytime data in a file is **line** oriented, first consideration is `fgets()` or `getline()` is you have it.  The format here can get fooled with `'\n'` or embedded `'\0'` in unexpected places.  So best to 1) read the line and 2) then parse it.